Error: Cross-reference between Middleware and Edge Function
I am already Project Settings > Build & Development Settings, I changed the Framework Presets from Others to Next.js and it working locally but production showing error. in locally npm build not showing error.
Traced Next.js server files in: 100.791ms
Created all serverless functions in: 357.86ms
Collected static files (public/, static/, .next/static): 12.911ms
Build Completed in /vercel/output [2m]
Deploying outputs...
Error: Cross-reference between Middleware and Edge Function.

Kindly provide detailed error logs, to have clear understating of the issue.
